# Parameter as filter in Redash

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, redash

I have this script

```
SELECT 
    SUM(gppn."wonAmount") AS "ss"
FROM 
    "GrantParticipant" AS gp
LEFT JOIN 
    "GrantParticipantProjectNomination" AS gppn ON gp."ID" = gppn."grantParticipantID"
LEFT JOIN 
    "User" as u ON gp."userID" = u."ID"
LEFT JOIN 
    "InstituteCabinetUser" as icu ON u."ID" = icu."userID"
LEFT JOIN 
    "NkoCabinetUser" as ncu ON u."ID" = ncu."userID"
LEFT JOIN 
    "GeoRegion" as gr ON u."regionID" = gr."ID"
LEFT JOIN 
    "GeoDistrict" as gd ON gr."districtID" = gd."ID"
WHERE 
    gppn.won IS TRUE
    AND "wonAmount" IS NOT NULL 
    AND ncu."ID" IS NOT NULL
    AND EXTRACT(Year FROM gp."createdAt") IN ({{ years }})
    AND (gr."name" IN ({{ regions }}))
    AND (gd."name" IN ({{ districts }}))
```

I have a problem: in the dashboard in the filter, I can't select the "Select all" or "Clear all" flag to select all values from the drop-down list of the parameter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abrLg.png)

How can I add these flags?

I manually selected all the positions from the drop-down list so that the values I needed were displayed on the dashboard